# How to create a 2d list with all same values but can alter multiple elements within? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to create a list that holds this exact format: `[[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2],[2]]`

and when `list[3][0] = 9` is called, the list becomes `[[2],[9],[2],[9],[2],[9],[2],[9],[2],[9]]`

How do I create the list in the first place that will allow me to change these many elements with only one line?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with list[3][0] = [0] ?

Comment: for creating 2-d list `d = [[2] for x in xrange(n)]` where n is the length of list items you want to create

Comment: I meant to say list[3][0] = 9, my bad. Edited. @warl0ck

Comment: What decides which elements are modified?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = [[2], [2]] * 5
>>> L
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
>>> L[3][0] = 9
>>> L
[[2], [9], [2], [9], [2], [9], [2], [9], [2], [9]]
```

This is because the same two lists are repeated over and over

```
>>> [id(x) for x in L]
[140053788793352, 140053788793288, 140053788793352, 140053788793288, 140053788793352, 140053788793288, 140053788793352, 140053788793288, 140053788793352, 140053788793288]
```

Comment: Ahh I see! The question makes so much sense now, thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the output, as it should give

```
[[2], [2], [2], [9], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

as the output.

Comment: Edited my original question regarding that, I meant to say list[3][0] = 9