# Python - Nested lists: One line code

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested, stack

```
A=???????????
print(A)
A[3][0]=5
print(A)
```

What can you put in the ?'s to make it output:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]

[[1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5]]
```

Hint: you can answer this question with an answer exactly as long as the number of ?'s. I tried the following.

```
A=[[1] for i in range(11)]
```

But this only gives me the first output. How can I make it so that I get the output given when `A[3][0]=5`?

Comment: But here you only change the third element? Not all odd ones...

Comment: you want to change all odd ones by changing only one element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: `A=[[1],[1]]*5`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a 2d list with all same values but can alter multiple elements within? (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432230/how-to-create-a-2d-list-with-all-same-values-but-can-alter-multiple-elements-wit)

Answer (score 2):

If you construct your list as

```
A = [[1],[1]]*5
```

then it contains 5 references to two lists. It's like saying:

```
X = [1]
Y = [1]
A = [X, Y, X, Y, X, Y, X, Y, X, Y]
```

Initially this looks like:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Then altering

```
A[3][0]=5
```

means you're altering the list that lies in every alternate position in `A`, giving you

```
[[1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5], [1], [5]]
```